# Email Spoofed From Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spoofing

One of my exchange users got an email that bounced back to them. They did not send the email and I'm a little confused at how they got it. I looked through the logs and do not see the email leaving our server. So I guess that is good, no open relay. However I'm a little worried about it still.

If this did not come from our server, how do I prevent this from happening?

Here is the header. I left everything as the original, except I change the following.

mailserver.outdomain.com (was our servers name)

143324627.79013003854714@ourdomain.com (did have our real domain)

PARIS FENTON  (did have a valid user email, Paris Fenton was not the users name but was in the original header)

```
Return-Path: <anor@sietsemafarms.com>
Received: from ppp005055110157.access.hol.gr (ppp005055110157.access.hol.gr
 [5.55.110.157])    by ftcpcs66l.faraday.com.tw (8.12.11/8.12.11) with ESMTP id
 t5FEgqMk024190 for <maxmao@faraday-tech.com>; Mon, 15 Jun 2015 22:42:54 +0800
Received: from [5.55.110.157] by mailserver.ourdomain.com; Tue, 16 Jun 2015
 00:49:41 +0200
Date: Tue, 16 Jun 2015 00:49:41 +0200
From: PARIS FENTON <validuser@ourdomain.com>
X-Mailer: The Bat! (v2.11) Business
Reply-To: <validuser@ourdomain.com>
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <143324627.79013003854714@ourdomain.com>
To: <someperson@somedomain.com>
Subject: You can increase the time of your act 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-AVG: 2013.0.3495 [4311.0.0/10020];0;
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AVStamp-Mailbox: AVGESE;14331;0;
```

Comment: You can't stop spoofing, you can only stop accepted spoofed messages using a system like SPF. That means if someone else is not detecting and rejecting spoofed messages, they can potentially recieve e-mails that spoof your domain or senders and there's nothing you can do about that.

Comment: So I'm correct in assuming this did not come from our server? 5.55.110.157 is not our server and looks like the sending server.

Comment: It's backscatter.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/9498/11060 -> E-mail is extremely easy to spoof details on. It almost certainly didn't originate on your server.